# Can BigLake tables detect schema changes on GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am thinking of a BigQuery setup, where

- the source files are CSVs stored on GCS, and
- tables are created from those files with BigLake
- tables are partitioned by `created_at` column

I would like to know how this setup can handle schema changes. The source files are actually exports from our application DB, so their schema can change when application schema is updated.

In order to set up a partition upon a specific column in the table, I noticed that I need to specify the schema beforehand and "Auto-detect schema" option cannot be used.

[image]

In this situation, will I have to update the schema manually every time the source schema is changed? Or will BigLake be able to handle the change on its own?

I have read the following page on BigLake, but I could not find them mentioning schema changes.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/biglake-quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigLake will not handle the table’s schema if the external table’s(i.e CSV in your case) schema gets changed. Once you upload the CSV into GCS and if the source file’s schema is different from the previous version then you will also need to update the table’s schema.

You can follow any of the [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#console)  methods to alter the schema of a table.